# Getting the last integer from a string

Tags: java, string, integer

Say I have a string `3 + 4 = 7` or `23 - 4 = 19`. I'm wondering how I would go about getting the last integer from the string so that it can be compared to another int.

Ive used this code:

```
int first = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" ")));
int second = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(result.indexOf('+')+1 , result.indexOf('=')));
```

to get the first and second integers for computation, but I can't seem to get the last integer in string when I'm using the method above. Is it just something I'm doing wrong or is there something else I need to do?

**I also cannot use arrays, regex, try/catch, or a SystemTokenizer.**

And my strings will not always be in the a + b = c format with the spaces or a single digit integer.
the strings are taken from a text file that is imported by the scanner. Here's a sample of the equations in the file:

```
11 - 2 = 9
12 - 1 = 11
7 + 1 = 8
7 - 3 = 4
7 + 2 = 9
14 + 4 = 18
```

Comment: Will your Strings always be in the format of `a + b = c` ?

Comment: If from your above example you need to retrieve 7 then:
`int first = Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));`

Comment: You can use charAt() with a for loop right??

Answer (score 3):

If all of your strings are in this format - `a + b = c`, then there is a simple way -

```
String[] parts = str.split("=");
String lastDigit = parts[parts.length - 1].trim();
int last = Integer.parseInt(lastDigit);
```

Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

**Update**

As per your requirement of not wanting to use regex, you can do something like this -

```
public int getLastDigit(String expression) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = expression.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = expression.charAt(i);

        if (c == '=') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            result.append(c); 
        }
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(result.reverse()
        .toString()
        .trim());
}

int last = getLastDigit("1 + 3 = 14");
System.out.println(last);     // will print 14
```

Comment: Isn't that an array though?

Comment: It also uses regex, and I can't use that either by demand of my instructor.

Answer (score 0):

This will work a lot easier:

```
String[] tokens = str.Split(" ");
int first = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int second = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
int last = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
```

Otherwise without arrays, use [`lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29):

```
int last = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" "), str.length()));
```

Comment: for some reason, the user mentioned he cannot use arrays. what you say?

Comment: @Ashish: that's why I also gave the second option which doesn't use arrays.

Comment: Yeap I noticed that - you second answer didn't load up when I put that comment. my apologies!

Answer (score 0):

simple use split and get index[1] to get last integer in string 
just split with "="

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
int last = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("=") + 1, str.length));
```

The idea is to get the index of the "=", and then parse the substring of there to the end.
I did "str.indexOf("=") + 1" so that it didn't include the "sign".

Comment: My bad I realized I forgot a parenthesis at the end. Let me know if it works now. (And what the error is if not please)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 19" 
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: At this point I'm kinda guessing because I don't have any code right in front of me but I'm assuming this is because of the space in " 19". From the Java docs: "The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign". So in other words, use .trim() before the last parenthesis to change the string from " 19" to "19".

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] tokens = str.split("=");
String finalDigit = tokens[tokens.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
class GetString{
publice static void main(String []args)
{
     string str,int x;
     Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\n");    //take each line
     while((str=s.next())!=NULL) 
     {
         str.trim();
         int first =  Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" ")));
         //Depending on weather the sign is '+' or '-' it will take the index of that 
         int second = Integer.parseInt(str.substring((x=str.indexOf('+')>-1?
                      str.indexOf('+'):str.indexOf('-'))+1 , result.indexOf('=')));
         int Third=  Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("="), str.Length-1))

     }

     s.close(); 
     }
}
```

**Its a general idea not a perfect code.Edits and suggestions are welcome.**

Comment: Unfortunately, there may be spaced on the right, so it just returns an error.

Comment: are the Equation part of one big string??If so do they have a separator?

Comment: Somewhat. There are several equations that are scanned in from a text file.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the sample of that text File??
Basically you have to take each equation from the file trim the spaces.And apply the above code.

Comment: the above code will take each line.Trim them and depending on weather its a plus or minus will take the second digit.and then take the third digit.Here instead of "input" you can give your file name.

Answer (score 0):

You would need trim the extracted digit, other wise it is possible to throw

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: " 7"

To extract the last digit, you may follow the below code

```
String str1="3 + 4 = 7";
String str2= str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf("=")+1).trim();
int i = Integer.parseInt(str2);
```

Comment: Essentially, the error is saying that there is still white space between the = and the digit.

Comment: quite not possible, provided you use trim() . Suggest you could edit your question with update code

Comment: I managed to fix it and got it working. I had to use .replaceAll(" " , "") to get rid of the white space before it would work.

Comment: @CherryBomb95 [String#replceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll) uses `regex` in background. Better use [String#replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace) method instead.